# Mavenized netbeans RCP project - layer.xml in branding module seems not being pickedup

Tags: netbeans, rcp, netbeans-plugins

I am trying to hide some of  netbeans default menu items  from my RCP application which is a mavenized nbm project.

I've added these items in layer.xml file in my Branding module. but it seems application totally ignoring the layer.xml file.

here is a snippet of layer.xml in branding module:

```
<filesystem>
         <folder name="File">
            <file name="org-netbeans-modules-editor-ExportHtmlAction.shadow_hidden"/>
            <file name="org-openide-actions-SaveAsAction.shadow_hidden"/>
        </folder>
         ...
</filesystem>
```

Note: Manifest file in branding module contains the OpenIDE-Module-Layer property which is pointing to the layer.xml `OpenIDE-Module-Layer: com/mypackage/layer.xml`

- how can i find if there is anything missing in my configuration or other places ?
- How can I make sure that  this file (layer.xml) is loaded by application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the module was Autoload and i think this was the problem. I removed the autload flag and problom has been resolved.

Comment: Does your splash screen and other branding elements still work after you've removed the autoload flag?